# Bootstrap Modal button not working, only on iOS

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have this Bootstrap Modal on my website that is working on everything, but Apple iOS.  Has anyone bumped into this/ have any thoughts of where to start in order to fix this? I have tried troubleshooting with an emulator and that seems to be working fine, just the Iphone doesn't seem to work.

Here is the button and modal, please let me know if you need any more information or for me to clarify.

Thank you!!

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--Button-->
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="tutorial__btn btn-green1 role-element leadstyle-link">Click Here To Sign Up</a>

<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter your email address and click the button below to get started.</h4>
     </div>
     
     <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="inline1" class="popup_window">
     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://mk165.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/5c8067cc4027e470304a973b2e87ce6d" class="infusion-form" method="POST">
      <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="5c8067cc4027e470304a973b2e87ce6d" />
      <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="Brooks Knee Pain" />
      <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1.48.0.48" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="inf_custom_UTMSource" name="inf_custom_UTMSource" value='<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']?>'/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="inf_custom_UTMMedium" name="inf_custom_UTMMedium" value='<?php echo $_GET['utm_medium']?>'/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="inf_custom_UTMTerm" name="inf_custom_UTMTerm" value='<?php echo $_GET['utm_term']?>'/>  
                            <input type="hidden" id="inf_custom_UTMCampaign" name="inf_custom_UTMCampaign" value='<?php echo $_GET['utm_campaign']?>'/>  
                            <input type="hidden" id="inf_custom_UTMContent" name="inf_custom_UTMContent" value='<?php echo $_GET['utm_content']?>'/>      
      <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
      <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_LastName" name="inf_field_LastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
      <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Phone1" name="inf_field_Phone1" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
      <input type="submit" value="GET STARTED HERE" />
     </form>
     <p class="policy">We hate SPAM and promise to keep your email address safe. </p>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just discovered the answer.  It seems that iOS needs an additional class which lets safari know that the button is clickable.  I added the additional class to the button and everything seems to be working.

```
.clickable {
cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The modal may not show on safari but on other browsers when the `href="#"` is missing.

Try this and see if this works:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal class="tutorial__btn btn-green1 role-element leadstyle-link">Click Here To Sign Up</a>
```

Comment: Are you saying, to write it like this? <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" class="tutorial__btn btn-green1 role-element leadstyle-link">Click Here To Sign Up</a>

Comment: Yes, try that and then if not just keep it as the one I put. It's a link so it still should work.

Comment: I gave it a try and it seems to stop the Modal from working on any device :/ Any other thoughts?

Comment: I've added a new answer for you, try that,].

Comment: In my case, the close button was inside a span element, changing to "a" link element happened to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Okay now try this bit of PHP:

Change

```
!--Button-->
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="tutorial__btn btn-green1 role-element leadstyle-link">Click Here To Sign Up</a>
```

to

```
!--Button-->
<?php 

$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");

if( !$iPod || !$iPhone || !$iPad){ 
    echo "<a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' class='tutorial__btn btn-green1 role-element leadstyle-link'>Click Here To Sign Up</a>"
} else{
    echo "<a data-toggle='modal' a href='#myModal' class='tutorial__btn btn-green1 role-element leadstyle-link'>Click Here To Sign Up</a>"
}

?>
```

What this should do is detect if it's an iOS device and if it is display the modal that works in iOS and if it isn't display the other one. Try that.