# Bootstrap modal not showing on submit button click on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

We have a scenario whereby when particular buttons on our website are clicked the processing takes 10 seconds or so - unfortunately there's not much we can do about this in the short-term because it's the time it takes to write data up to Dynamics CRM.

As a short-term solution, we wanted to show a bootstrap modal alerting the user that something is still happening..i.e. it's processing. We thought we would show the modal after about 1 or 2 seconds, that way if the process finished quickly the user wouldnt even see the modal, if it was slow they would.

So, we start with a button in our HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" class="link-button large-plus-link-button primary" data-toggle-processing-modal="true"/>
```

Under which is the modal itself:

```
<div id="processingModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-blogpost-label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            Loading...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then we have a javascript function to show the modal:

```
    $("[data-toggle-processing-modal='true']").on('click', function(e) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#processingModal').modal('show');
    }, 1000);

})
```

This works in all desktop browsers that we've tested so far, and mobile versions of Android, however the modal doesnt show at all on IOS devices. I believe it is something to do with the fact that the page has started submitting and the reason I think this is because if I prevent the page from submitting by adding e.preventDefault() within the javascript function, it works! BUT, the page doesn't get submitted of course!

I've racked my brains, but I can't seem to think of a way around this - can anyone suggest any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Kind regards,
dotdev

Comment: You should use `ajax` to submit the form after the `e.preventDefault()` call

Comment: Are you using AJAX Or something else to submit you form.

Comment: No, in this instance the forms are not using Ajax...is that pretty much the only option?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139346/bootstrap-modal-button-not-working-only-on-ios