# modal not open in react-native android

Tags: react-native

I am Developing react-native Android Sample App. Firstly I Created One Page inside Tab bar Bottom On Page ... In TabBar Contains OneTabPage have contains  open Two Modals ( one Is Using Edit and another Date showing to modal's custom Desing) modal and one Button has EditButton when  i was click on editIcon show Modal it's working fine iOS. But in android when i was go to click on next tab and come back to current Page it's not working Modal means not Open(android).

I am following refer this link : https://github.com/bodyflex/react-native-simple-modal
This is my Code:

```
<Modal
            open={this.state.open}
            offset={0}
            animationDuration={200}
            animationTension={40}
            open={this.state.open}
            closeOnTouchOutside={true}
            modalDidOpen={() => console.log('modal did open')}
            modalDidClose={() => this.setState({open: false})}
            style={{flexGrow: 1,
            height:windowSize.height/2.5}}>
            <View style={styles.modelView}>
            <View style={{flex:.25, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center', color:'black'}}>
            {this.state.product_title}
            </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:.35, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <View style={styles.modelIncDecButton}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:.15, justifyContent:'space-around', alignItems:'center'}}  onPress={this.decrementMethode.bind(this)}>
            <Image style={styles.incrementDecrementIcon} source={require('@images/decrementIcon.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={{flex:.05, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
           <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center',color:'black'}}>
            {this.state.product_quantity}
            </Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:.15, justifyContent:'space-around', alignItems:'center'}}  onPress={this.incrementMethode.bind(this)}>
            <Image style={styles.incrementDecrementIcon} source={require('@images/incrementIcon.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:.15,  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center',color:'black'}}>
             £ {(Math.floor(this.state.product_total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)}
            </Text>
            </View>
             <View style={{flex:.25, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.updateButton} onPress={this.updateMethode.bind(this)}>
             <Text style={styles.updateButtonText}>
             Update
            </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>

           </View>
      </Modal>
```

the above code based i am following this link : 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/bodyflex/react-native-simple-modal)

Thans in Advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139346/bootstrap-modal-button-not-working-only-on-ios